# I want to send the value from textbox to action method parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, model-view-controller

```
    <input type="text" id="txtValue" />
    <input type="button" value="search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SearchById", "EmployeeRecords") ? Value='+ $('#txtValue').val()"/>
```

This is the test box mentioned above

```
    [HttpPost("{EmployeeId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchById(string EmployeeId)
{
var ret = await SvcEmployeeRecords.SearchEmployeeAsync(EmployeeId);
return View("Index", ret);    
}
```

And this is the controller code.
the breakpoint is not at all hitting can any one help me with this?

Comment: You have a post action (HttpPost-attribute) but all you are doing is a http get request, hence the action is not hit. You need a form-element in the html to send a http post request to the server.

Comment: no instead of value i need to pass the name of the param now its working thank you

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.